# Delete specific elements from a list in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list containing some countries and relative capitals.
I would like to delete only the capitals to create a new countryList[] and viceversa.
Here's my list

```
countryCapitalList= ['AFGHANISTAN=', 'KABUL', 'ALASKA=', 'JUNEAU', 'ALBANIA=', 'TIRANA', 'ALGERIA=', 'ALGERI']
```

As the countries correspond to an even number I was trying this way:

```
    i = 0

    for x in countryCapitalList[:]:
        del countryCapitalList[i]
        i = i + 1



    print countryCapitalList
```

but I get this error:

```
del countryCapitalList[i]
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

I really don't understand why. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for this specific case, just delete elements with odd index:

```
In [1452]: countryList=countryCapitalList[:]

In [1453]: del countryList[1::2]

In [1454]: countryList
Out[1454]: ['AFGHANISTAN=', 'ALASKA=', 'ALBANIA=', 'ALGERIA=']
```

Answer (score 1):

The exception you're getting is because you're deleting by index, rather than by value. The list is getting shorter during the iteration and therefore the index is no longer meaningful.  Instead, I would delete by value,

```
for x in countryCapitalList[:]:
     if isCapital(x):
          countryCapitalList.remove(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

If all your country entries have "=" in them, and nothing else does, the cleanest way is

```
countryCapitalList = [x for x in countryCapitalList if "=" not in x]
```

This is using [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). It goes through the list, selecting only those entries that do not have "=" in them.